# How to select single checkbox in a recycler view with multiple checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

There are answers of this questions but none of them solved my problem .Below is my code .

```
  public class QuizAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuizAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
Context context;
private List<Quiz_G_S> quiz_g_sList = null;
int selectedPosition = -1;


public QuizAdapter(Context context, List<Quiz_G_S> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.quiz_g_sList = list;
}


@Override
public QuizAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.quiz_single_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final QuizAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final int pos = position;

    holder.answers.setText(quiz_g_sList.get(pos).getMCQ());

    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            quiz_g_sList.get(pos).setChecked(true);

        }
    });

    if (quiz_g_sList.get(pos).isChecked()) {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    } else {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

    }





}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return quiz_g_sList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView answers;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        answers = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quiz_adap_ans);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.quiz_adap_check);

    }
}
```

Above is my adapter code.

This is my Quiz_G_S class

```
public class Quiz_G_S {


String MCQ;
int Rank;
boolean checked;

public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}

public String getMCQ() {
    return MCQ;
}

public void setMCQ(String mcq) {
    this.MCQ = mcq;
}

public int getRank() {
    return Rank;
}

public void setRank(int rank) {
    this.Rank = rank;
}
```

}

What i want to do is if i check a checkbox then all checkboxes will set unchecked except the one I checked
 There is an error on notifyDataSetChanged. I guess the logic is right but i don't know how to refresh checkbox state.The only thing I know is notifyDataSetChanged is there any other method to refresh or is there any workaround for this problem

Answer (score 1):

try below code:

1. Define one more Object in your `Quiz_G_S` Class `boolean isChecked`
2. Get the position of checked `CheckBox`

   `selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();`
3. Reset all other objects of List like below:

   ```
   for (int i=0; i<list.size ; i++) 
   {  
     if (selectedPosition==i)  
        list.get(i).setIsChecked(true); 
     else     
        list.get(i).setIsChecked(false);
   }
   ```
4. call `QuizAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();`.
5. In last, check selected check box like below:

   ```
   if (list.get(position).getIsChecked()) 
   {
      holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
   } else {
     holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 selectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
```

maintain a flag inside your object class which will be set on Check of particular checkbox suppose "checked" is your flag that you have created in your object class then

on check change listener set it to true

```
if (isChecked) {
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);

} else {
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

}
```

**EDIT**

```
 if (quiz_g_sList.get(pos).isChecked) {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);

    } else {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

    }
```

**UPDATE**

change your object class to this

```
 public class Quiz_G_S {

        String MCQ;
        int Rank;
        boolean checked;

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return checked;
        }

        public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public String getMCQ() {
            return MCQ;
        }

        public void setMCQ(String mcq) {
            this.MCQ = mcq;
        }

        public int getRank() {
            return Rank;
        }

        public void setRank(int rank) {
            this.Rank = rank;
        }
    }
```

Comment: but how will i refresh the state of checkboxes?

Comment: what is setChecked (true) in quiz_g_sList.get(pos).setChecked(true);.Is this a method which i have to create?

Comment: As i told you, you need to create flag in your object class i.e. Quiz_G_S

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get it .As i am new to android .Can u plz explain a bit more

Comment: can you provide me your class named as Quiz_G_S

Comment: thanks for the help but still my code working remains the same. I am guessing that the data needs to be refreshed

Comment: did you called notifyDataSetChanged(); after setting it true

Comment: whats the issue now, can you update your question with your updated code?

Comment: issue is all the checkboxes are checked, what i want is only a single checkbox is checked. And i have edited my code plz have a look

Comment: please check your arraylist and then go through my code you did it wrong way

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented like this, where i got output.

```
if(view == null) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_checkbox_adapter_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.todoItemTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_tv);
        holder.checkedTextView = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id._item_checkbox);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.todoItemTextView.setTag("" + position);
    holder.checkedTextView.setChecked(displayModel.isFinished());

    holder.checkedTextView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            try {
                String tag = (String) holder.todoItemTextView.getTag();
                int pos = Integer.parseInt(tag);
                todoItemBeanList.get(pos).setFinished(isChecked);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you have to do:

1. Pass checked position to Activity/Fragment/Presenter 
   (Implement click/checkChanged listener). Examples can be found here: [RecyclerView onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)
2. Save position of checked item into a variable (say `int selectedPosition`).
3. Then update previously checked item on each click/check:

`if (position != selectedPosition) {
        // user selected another item so previous one should be updated
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
        selectedPosition = position;
}`